# OLS - unbiased estimators - underlying assumptions

Tags: self-study, least-squares, assumptions, consistency

Let's assume that we have $\ y_i = x_i$$\beta$+$\ ε_i$

I would argue that the estimator is still unbiased and consistent even if we have $\ E[εi|xj] \ne 0 $ since it does not violate the exogeneity assumption.

Would that be sufficient as an explanation?

Comment: $E[ε_i|x_j] \ne 0$ _does_ violate the exogeneity assumption.

Comment: ...because the strict exogeneity assumtpion needed for unbiasedness is $E(\varepsilon_i \mid \mathbf X) = 0$ i.e. it refers not only to the regressors of the same observation, but to all regressors in the sample.

Comment: But in my equation I only have observation i

Comment: As written, your equation has error of observation $i$ against regressors of observation $j$... except if you meant to write $x_{ij}, \; j=1,..,k$ the number of regressors.

Comment: Ok, the equations is correct. Just not sure why I cannot ignore x_j but will think about it

Comment: Write the estimator expression in matrix form and you will see that you require each and every error to be mean-independent of each and every regressor in the sample. Note: for consistency the requirement is indeed much weaker